# Auto incrementing row count excel

Tags: excel

I'm inputting data into an excel file currently, is it possible to count as I insert the data? Currently I have a hacky formula for short term

```
=COUNTA (A1:A1000)
```

Comment: There are better ways of locating the last used row in a column.

Comment: I haven't used excel in years, what terms should I search for online?

Comment: @Jeeped - why do you think the OP wants the last used row in a column? OP - if you want last used row, google "last used row in a column excel".

Comment: @Vityata I thought that might be a bit simple, I thought he might be implying if I find the last row used in a column it I could dynamically count from A1 for example

Comment: What **exactly** are you trying to achieve? Like the endgoal behind counting rows. Because it sounds there is a more elegant solution to this, but which we obviously can't suggest if we don't know what's the purpose behind all this row counting.

Comment: Currently I'm scanning bar codes into a spread sheet, currently there's 42,111 items but they want a count for the day as I progress, thinking about it I may have worded the initial question wrong, I'm awful at multi tasking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make it even hackier, it would work for the whole column:

`=COUNTA(A:A)`

Comment: Haha it is tempting

Comment: Accepting this because it amused me, I suddenly realised what I want to do is slightly more complex